# MySQL Java Data Insertion error

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Im trying to connect to mySQL DB and perform an Insert on the 3 columns osName,version,notes in my Java application. The tutorial im following is http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement. Any input or comments are helpful. Here is my Database info -

CREATE TABLE `oslog`.`entry` (
   `osName` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
   `version` VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
   `notes` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY ( `osName` )
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

```
 package com.tutorialspoint.struts2;

 import java.sql.*;

 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

 public class HelloWorldAction extends ActionSupport{
private String osName;
private String version;
private String notes;

public String execute() throws Exception {
    return "success";
 }
{

        try
        {
            // created a datbase connection
            String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
            String myURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/HelloWorld";
            Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, "root", "");

            //insert statement

            String query = "INSERT INTO oslog.entry (osName,version,notes " + 
            "values osName, version, notes";

            //mysql insert preparedstatement

            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, osName);
            preparedStmt.setString(2, version);
            preparedStmt.setString(3, notes);
            //excute the preparedstatement
            preparedStmt.execute();
            conn.close();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Got an Exception!");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }


}




    public String getOsName() {
    return osName;
}
public void setOsName(String osName) {
    this.osName = osName;
}
public String getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(String version) {
    this.version = version;
}
public String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}
public void setNotes(String notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}

public void validate()
{
    if (osName == null || osName.trim().equals(""))
    { 
        addFieldError("osName","The OS name is required");
    }
    if (version == null || version.trim().equals(""))
    {
        addFieldError("version","The OS version is required");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I believe you need round brackets around your values in the query; you've also not closed the first round bracket (around column names).

Comment: Does not return an error. I have my jsp and actions to be successful no matter what happens.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values null, null, null' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

I see you are using `PreparedStatement`
You need to change your `query` String from:

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO oslog.entry (osName,version,notes " + 
        "values osName, version, notes";
```

to

```
 String query = "INSERT INTO oslog.entry(osName,version,notes) " + 
        "values (?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: String query = "INSERT INTO oslog.entry(osName,version,notes) " + 
        "values (?, ?, ?)";       That didn't fix it. I dont have any errors coming up.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `PreparedStatement`, so your query should have placeholders. Try this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO oslog.entry (osName,version,notes) " + 
            "values (?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'values null, null, null' at line 1" is the error i get.

Comment: @Kyas That is because you never initialize the variables that you pass to `preparedStmt` (`osName`,`version`, `notes`) and your table doesn't accept `null` for those columns.

Comment: I can change my table but How would i initialize the variables?

Comment: @Kyas you have not used the string i mentioned in my answer, you seems to be missing '(' after values. I believe your sql string is like "values ?, ?, ?";  instead of "values (?, ?, ?)";

Comment: I have changed the action file as such:                          String query = "INSERT INTO oslog.entry (osName,version,notes) " + 
            "values (?, ?, ?)";

Comment: @Kyas Ok so i assume no error/exception. If you are not able to see the inserts happening then you may try executeUpdate instead of execute method. Replace preparedStmt.execute(); with preparedStmt.executeUpdate();

Comment: @Kyas the value of variable osName is null whereas your table entry does not allow null values for the column osName